# How to change resource type from ServletContextResource to FileSystemResource in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-kafka

I have trouble opening a certificate store in Spring boot. My app is a war-file, and the cert-store is on an external path.

The error I get is: 
`nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Resource 'ServletContext resource [/"file:C:/cert/client-keystore.jks"]' must be on a file system`

I understand this error as Spring trying to open a `ServletContextResource`, while I guess it should be a `FileSystemResource`. How can I force Spring to reclassify the resource?

File is there:
[image]

The path is read from application properties as:

```
spring.kafka.producer.ssl.key-store-location="file:C:/cert/client-keystore.jks"
```

The file is read as:
`@PropertySource(value = { "file:c:/path/application.properties" })`

Thankful for any help.

BR, SF

Comment: Are you sure your file `client-keystore.jks` is located in your file system ? When I read this error, this is what I understand.

Comment: Remove the `"` from the property value.

Comment: It is in the file system. I think Spring is looking for the file in the classpath though.

Comment: If I remove the double quotes I still get: Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:C:\cert\client-keystore.jks (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_211]

Comment: Removing the double quotes makes it at least processed as a `FileResource`. However the file cannot be opened. Make sure that the file is in that location, and that the file is readable from the proces you are running.

Comment: Edit the question to show the full stack trace (when the quotes are removed); Spring Boot's auto configuration for Kafka has logic in `KafkaProperties.Ssl.resourceToPath()` to convert the Spring Resource to an absolute path for Kafka configuration (Kafka doesn't know anything about Spring Resources). This conversion generates the original error in your post.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working after changing the syntax to:
spring.kafka.producer.ssl.key-store-location=C:/cert/client-keystore.jks

Removing **file:** from the path.

BR, SF